# NODEJS: Is there an easy way to convert a date from another language like Portuguese to English

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way, using NODE/Javascript, to convert a Date that is in Portuguese to English?

For example I have a Portuguese Date `08/05/2020` which correctly is `May 08, 2020` because it is DD/MM/YYYY. However, when I added that to the Date function, it translates to `August 05, 2020`, which is wrong.

How can I tell NODE/JS that the date being passed is in a different language and format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use functions in moment.js library to convert between date types.

Look at the different types of formats available in its documentation.

https://momentjs.com/

Comment: It seems MomentJs will do the trick. Once I come up with a solution for my issue, I will post back.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just Portuguese to English (DD/MM/YYYY -> MM/DD/YYYY as I understand it), then it's super easy to do with string operations:

```js
const date1 = "08/05/2020";

const [b, a, c] = date1.split("/");

const date2 = [a, b, c].join("/");

console.log(date2);
console.log(new Date(date2).toString());
```